# How to include number of not-yet-decayed radioactive atoms in MLE?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, censoring

Since this question received absolutely zero attention, here's a complete rephrase with the aim of significantly shortening it.

---

I have a potful of $n$ radioactive atoms. I spend $t_\text{max}$ = 1 hour recording the times when I see an atom decay.  Then I'm left with $n-k$ atoms in the pot and $k$ measurements of the times: $t_1, \dots, t_k$.  As you know, the distribution of these times is exponential, $p(t) = a e^{-a t}$, and I wish to find the decay rate $a$ using maximum likelihood estimation.

One way is to restrict the distribution to the interval $[0, t_\text{max}]$ and use $p(t) = a e^{-a t} / (1-e^{-a t_\text{max}})$ for the deriving the MLE.

This method doesn't use the information that there were $n-k$ atoms left after $t_\text{max}$ (which in itself would be usable for estimating $a$, where this estimate may be somewhat different from what I get from the MLE).

**Question:** How can I make use of the number of remaining atoms in the fitting procedure, while still using maximum likelihood estimation?

---

My question is in fact general, and could be asked about any distribution defined on $[0, \infty)$, not only the exponential one.  The story above was just an example that made it easier to explain the problem concisely.

Comment: Is that any different from having censored data, where all you know for the $n-k$ atoms that didn't decay is that their decay time is greater than $t_{\mathrm{max}}$?

Comment: I describe and illustrate the method of using MLE with censored data at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49456.  Does that fully answer your general question?  Incidentally, your specific question is also addressed using techniques of survival analysis.

Comment: *Don't* treat the data as truncated but as right-censored, with likelihood $[1-P(t_{\mathrm{max}})]^{n-k}\prod_{i=1}^k p(t_i)$, where $P(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: @whuber and Scortchi Possible, I need a bit of time to read what censored data means and read the other thread.  I'll delete this if it turns out to be a duplicate.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Please do not delete it! If it turns out to be a duplicate, then (because it is full of useful key words) it will most likely show up better in future searches and help lead people to the answers they seek.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what happens in cases like this (or what I think should happen), as this question is clearly not a duplicate of the other question, which nevertheless has a answer that suits this one.

Comment: @Scortchi Yesterday night I was thinking of the same what you wrote (you comment with the formula), but I made the mistake of assuming that we can't include both $1-P(t_\text{max})$ and $p(t_i)$ in the product because one is a probability and the other is a probability density, thus they are not comparable.  Now I do see why they can actually both be included and this does indeed solve the problem.  Thanks!  (Just did a numerical experiment to verify that it works---for my peace of mind.)

Comment: @Scortchi Well, if you wish you can post a short answer, and flag it as a duplicate afterwards.  If the goal is to make these useful for future visitors, it's the best thing to do.

Comment: @Scortchi A post in another thread that answers a new question is ordinarily considered sufficient reason to convert the new question into a duplicate. The new question remains visible but links to the old post. Over time this process can create a "cloud" of questions that ask the same thing in differing ways, with all of them pointing to a common thread of answers and comments.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks - on reflection that seems to be exactly what should happen.