# Bayesian model with maybe-missing data

Tags: bayesian, stan

Suppose we have data that come from a normal distribution with unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma$ parameters. The twist is that each value is missing with the given probability $p$, i.e. we observe a vector of pairs: `(value, probability)`. In particular, if $p_i=0$ we should treat the $i$-th observation as missing (removing it from the model altogether) and if $p_i=1$ we should simply add $y_i ~ N(\mu, \sigma)$ to the log-likelihood for that $i$.

In other words, I wonder what to put in the `model` section in the stan model below:

```
data {
  int N;
  real y[N]; // the value
  real p[N]; // probability the value is valid. Zero means the value should completely discarded as missing.
}
parameters {
  real mu;
  real<lower = 0> sigma;
}
model {
  for (i in 1:N) {
  // y[i] ~ normal(mu, sigma) // baseline
  // target += normal_lpdf(y[i], mu, sigma) + log(p[i]) // this approach is wrong
  }
}
```

When I studied Bayesian statistics some 10 years ago, I learned that problems that involve probabilities of probabilities were not solvable (unless the probability could be treated as a parameter). I hope I am wrong.

---

One obvious walk-around of the problem is the Monte-Carlo approach: toss a (Bernoulli) coin for each parameter $p_i$; if positive - include the $i$-th data point in the sample vector. Then solve the standard normal problem using the sampled data. Repeat the process for each of the $N$ simulations from the dataset. At the end aggregate all the (Bayesian) results together.

Comment: In what sense do you use the term "censored"? Censoring means that we know that an observation falls in a range of values. For example if a survival time (in days) is centered at 100 we know that survival is at least 100 days; the range is $[100, \infty)$. The lower bound 100 is informative, so we won't throw away this observation. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144041/237901). Also, are the probabilities $p_i$ only 0s and 1s?

Comment: You are right, sorry for a misnomer. What I mean is "maybe-missing", not "maybe-censored". I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have you seen the [Missing Data and Partially Known Parameters](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/missing-data-and-partially-known-parameters.html) section of the Stan user guide? I'm still not clear though: If some observations are missing and you want to ignore them completely, why don't you remove them beforehand from `y[N]`?

Comment: taking inspiration from the power prior (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4626399/) folks, one option would be to exponentiate the likelihood component of a given observation by $p_i$, or, in other words, to set y[i] ~ normal(mu, sigma/p[i]). If stan can't handle infinite variances, (which, it's stan, so probably it can't), then let eps=1e-6 and the stddev param is instead sigma/(p[i]+eps). You'd want to verify that this doesn't give ludicrous estimates for $\sigma$, but it will definitely discount "bad" data.

Comment: @dipetkov That's the main issue: they are neither 100% missing nor existing. What we have are data points that contain a validity metric, measured conveniently in probability that this specific data point is valid.

Comment: @JohnMadden That would work qualitatively, but I worry why this particular form? Why not e.g. $y_i \sim N(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{p_i^2})$?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski perhaps for no greater reason than the reason we are doing $y_i \sim Normal(a,b)$ rather than $y_i \sim Laplace(a,b)$ ;). But yes, we could generally consider any function of $p_i$ that is monotically increasing and fix 0 and 1. If some of these functions lead to a very different analysis than others, that would be worth noting.

Comment: I apologize but I still don't get what you want the data point to contribute to the likelihood when it's partially invalid. My understanding is that you'd like to set up a mixture of two components : $p_i \times \text{component}_1 + (1-p_i) \times \text{component}_2$. This is easy to do in Stan with [log_mix](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/vectorizing-mixtures.html). However, so far you've specified component 1 only: $p_i \times \text{Normal}(\mu, \sigma)$. For the mixture likelihood idea to work you'd need to come up with a meaningful component 2 as well.