# How to estimate mean and variance of censored normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, censoring

Supposing I have data which I know is normally distributed, but because the recording process is right censored, how do I estimate the parameters of the distribution?

Comment: One solution (out of many possible) is given, with working code, at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49456.

Comment: My answer was wrong, so I deleted it.  Probably the formula's you are looking for are on page 20 of http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/presentations/truncated_normal.pdf

Comment: @fcoppens Your (deleted) answer and your comment confuse censoring with truncation. It is important to distinguish them and treat them differently.

Comment: Thanks @whuber! Do you happen to have pointers to any of the other many possible methods? Or at least search terms I should use?

Comment: Censoring is a big deal in some specialized (but popular) fields, which are busy rediscovering each other's methods. One set of methods comes from *survival analysis.*  Another is developed in *chemometrics* (which is primarily concerned with left-censoring, but everything applies to right-censoring too). See [Dennis Helsel's book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002278.html), for instance.

Comment: It looks like the answer @kjetilbhalvorsen cited does answer the question, but the title of the question is so different that it looks like a completely different question