# Choosing between two models, logistic regression vs mixed model

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, binomial-distribution

I have a dataset, the distribution looks like this, before and after log-transformation. The data tends to separate itself towards two extremes, thus motivating me to classify them as binary and fit logistic regression. On the other hand, fitting a mixed-model on the log-transformed data might be a simpler way to go about this.

I have tried to do both, and the results are not that different. How would you qualify which fit is more appropriate? I have been using R in my analysis and fit them using `glm()` and `lmer()`.

Appreciate the feedback, Thanks! 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the search for the right transformation is not going to help materially.  From your graphs I'm guessing that many values would have fallen below 0 and some above 100 if the measurement approach had allowed.  In this circumstance the most effective technique is probably censored regression, also called tobit regression.  [The UCLA data-analysis site](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/tobit-models/) will probably be helpful.  Probably also [this worked example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49443/how-to-model-this-odd-shaped-distribution-almost-a-reverse-j/49456).